# cout, XOR, and fileIO formatting issues in C++

Tags: c++, file, encryption, io, xor

I'm having issues I've never seen before since I've started messing with the XOR operator and simple, single character key encryption. The text always has a random ascii character at the end of it after it runs through the program a second time. Another issues is that the texts "Pre-order" and "Post-order" are modified alternatively after every iteration of the program. I'm sure most of this is simply due to beginner mistakes, especially a lack of experience with IO in the way that these issues are appearing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifile;
    ofstream ofile;
    string toProc;
    string file;
    char key = ' ';
    cout << "Enter file location: \n";
    cin >> file;
    cout << "Enter key: \n";
    cin >> key;
    ifile.open(file);
    if(ifile.is_open())
    {
        char temp;
        temp = ifile.get();
        toProc.push_back(temp);
        while(ifile.good())
        {
            temp = ifile.get();
            toProc.push_back(temp);
        }

        ifile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No file found.\n";
    }
    cout << "Pre action: " << toProc << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < toProc.size(); i++)
        toProc[i] ^= key;
    cout << "Post action: " << toProc << endl;
    ofile.open(file);
    ofile << toProc;
    ofile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` function of `std::ifstream`, which you use to retrieve characters from the input file, returns `eof` (end-of-file) when it hits the end of the file. You need to check for this (instead of checking `ifile.good()` in the loop).

The way it's written now, it takes the `eof` as a character and appends it to the string. That (i.e. the xor'ed version of it) is the funny character you are getting in your output.

Here is a simple loop that reads characters from `std::cin` using `get()` and echos them on `STDOUT`. It performs the check for `eof` correctly. You can fit this into your code, using `ifile` instead of `std::cin`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char c;
  while ((c = std::cin.get()) != std::istream::traits_type::eof())
    std::cout.put(c);

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I should also mention that the `get()` function reads character by character, and there isn't really any good reason for that. I would use `getline()` or `read()` to read bigger chunks.

Comment: Note that `getLine()` does not work on the decryption part as the result of the encryption may include all kinds of control characters. To perform meaningful encryption you should use an explicit character encoding (but then again, you should not use single char encryption either, for testing purposes you should be able to get away with it).

Comment: @owlstead Ah yes, that's right. I had somehow assumed the encryption was only applied to alphabetic characters here, but you are right, it affects line endings as well.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly after I checked for eof. File IO was always an issue for me.